# Should the "Atago" be identified as such in Midway during "search"?

Tags: midway

The *Atago* is a Japanese heavy cruiser. Ordinarily one cruiser can't be told apart from another during a "search." (This is a reconnaissance mission by planes or ships that locates enemy ships for your bombers.)

In fact, the game rules conceded that ship *type* identification was often erroneous. In the game, Japanese ship types are (aircraft) carriers, battleships and cruisers, while the Americans have only carriers and cruisers.

What gives the *Atago* its importance is that it is the flagship of the transports carrying the Midway invasion force. Within the parameters of the game, the fate of the transports (sunk or surviving) is "represented" by the fate of the *Atago.*

In the interests of a better simulation, the *Atago* can be characterized as "the cruiser surrounded by eight transports," or "the flagship of the transport fleet." Should we give the Japanese a fourth ship type, transports, and use the word "transports" in reference to the *Atago*, even though the rules call her a "cruiser?" Are transports, in fact, sufficiently distinguishable from cruisers for this to work?

Comment: What's your goal? Are you looking to achieve better simulation, or improved pay balance, or handicapping, or some combination and/or other goal? A short summary of the mechanics of "search" in the game might also allow non-experts in the game to weigh in.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Re-worked the question incorporating your suggestions.